# Mounting a drive

Tags: mount

I am a new user of Ubuntu. But i am facing a problem now. Just before starting it says that a drive has not been mount yet.

It says:

> Wait for continue or click 's' to skip or click 'm' to recover
>   manually

while Ubuntu is starting up, the screen appears with "ubuntu" and below that the exact lines are written like this:

> The disk drive for /windows is not ready yet or not present. continue
>   to wait, or Press S to skip mounting or M for maual recovery

and it remains like this until I click 's'. How can I solve this problem?

See below my `/etc/fstab`:

```
mehedi@Mehedi:~$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=9befcfc0-96e4-45dc-959c-addd5e440498 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=f29ebd22-4ccf-4d45-8c57-ad18616e91f5 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /windows was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=381C-CD68  /windows        vfat    utf8,umask=007,gid=46 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=6c2d8d89-38d6-4590-9980-279c3d7954bf none            swap    sw              0       0
mehedi@Mehedi:~$
```

Comment: Also Post fstab. from terminal 'cat /etc/fstab' and tell us which partition is not mounting. Either device that is entry in fstab is missing or partition needs repairs.

Comment: i have written the codes as you asked. as i am a new user..so i dont know much about ubuntu. so please pardon me if i have mistaken

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this with the following command

```
sudo -i -e 's/UUID=381C-CD68/#UUID=381C-CD68/g' /etc/fstab
```

This will comment out (add a # ) to the front of the line for your windows partiton.

You can fix fstab by re-writing the line.

Post the output of

```
sudo blkid
```

and we can re-write

Answer (score -1):

```
mehedi@Mehedi:~$ sudo blkid
```

[sudo] password for mehedi: 
/dev/sda1: UUID="9befcfc0-96e4-45dc-959c-addd5e440498" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="6c2d8d89-38d6-4590-9980-279c3d7954bf" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sda3: UUID="f29ebd22-4ccf-4d45-8c57-ad18616e91f5" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda4: LABEL="Elmesh" UUID="0DA0CAA85371CC88" TYPE="ntfs" 
mehedi@Mehedi:~$

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) We're very sorry, but this is not a good place to put a comment to a request from someone.  Please press the "delete" button to reverse the negative reputation you now got and press "add comment" and type the information there to inform bodhi that you left a comment as he's now not aware of this.